# How can I make Flash work with a SharePoint List instead of XML?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, sharepoint, actionscript, sharepoint-2010

I heard from an article somewhere that Flash can now use SharePoint lists instead of an XML file.

However, I'm having trouble locating a tutorial which will explain how to get a Flash app to draw from a SharePoint list.

Anyone know any good tutorials?

I'm working with SharePoint 2010, Flash CS4, and I'm currently using AS3 to pull in data from the XML file on the Flash app.

Answer (score 1):

Try this: [Displaying SharePoint Content with Flash](http://msmvps.com/blogs/anguslogan/archive/2005/10/30/73501.aspx).

(It's the first [google result for as3 sharepoint](http://www.google.com/search?q=as3+sharepoint))

Comment: Yes, I have seen that particular tutorial. Unfortunately it's meant for Flex and a much older version of SharePoint. I've been unsuccessful at adapting it to AS3 + SP2010. The author has stated that he no longer has the setup and can no longer answer any of the newer questions. There's got to be something more current.

Answer (score 0):

There's a tutorial that explains how to use the new client object model from javascript. Flash can talk to javascript, so that may be an option.

http://snipplr.com/view/37785/sharepoint-2010-read-from-list-using-ecmascript/

Comment: Interesting. It's missing some critical parts to make it work, but it proposes a new possibility. Could you use JavaScript to pull the XML from the SharePoint list first and then pass it to the Flash app as a parameter?

Comment: I think you can: http://active.tutsplus.com/tutorials/actionscript/pass-values-to-a-swf-with-javascript-and-swfobject-basix/